# cross domain tinymcePopup (Result of expression 'tinymce' [undefined] is not an object.)

Tags: javascript, air, tinymce, cross-domain, inline

I have an AIR application which has tinyMCE js into it. I have added a button on tinyMCE toolbar , upon click of which an inlinepopup window appear. this inline popup loads an url

```
            var aa=tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            url : 'http://localhost/Save.html',
            width : 520,
            height : 340,
            resizable : "yes",
            inline : true,
            close_previous : "yes"

            });
```

**Save.html code:**

```
 <script src="http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/editor"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<script>

var editor;
window.onload = function () 
{   
  editor = com.wiris.jsEditor.JsEditor.newInstance({'language': 'en'});
      editor.insertInto(document.getElementById('editorContainer'));
}
```

Now problem is----
When i run my AIR application i get an error
Result of expression 'tinymce' [undefined] is not an object.

I suspect a cross-domain issue because 
when i alert in Save.html
`alert(window.document.domain); returns "localhost"`

when i alert in AIR application Mxml (inside ) js
`alert(window.document.domain); returns " "`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions & advice.